# Using PHP to determine what HTML to write out

Tags: php, html

This block of PHP code prints out some information from a file in the directory, but I want the information printed out by echo to be used inside the HTML below it.  Any help how to do this?  Am I even asking this question right?  Thanks.

```
if(array_pop($words) == "fulltrajectory.xyz") {
  $DIR = explode("/",htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]));
  $truncatedDIR = array_pop($DIR);
  $truncatedDIR2 = ''.implode("/",$DIR);

  $conffile = fopen("/var/www/scmods/fileviewer/".$truncatedDIR2."/conf.txt",'r');

  $line = trim(fgets($conffile));
  while(!feof($conffile)) {
  $words = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);  
  if(strcmp($words[0],"FROZENATOMS") == 0) {
    print_r($words);
    $frozen = implode(",", array_slice(preg_split('/\s+/',$line), 1));
    }  
  $line = trim(fgets($conffile));
  }

  echo $frozen . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The above code prints out some information using an echo.  The information printed out in that echo I want in the HTML code below where it has $PRINTHERE.  How do I get it to do that?  Thanks.

```
$("#btns").html(Jmol.jmolButton(jmolApplet0, "select atomno=[$PRINTHERE]; halos on;", "frozen on")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that your file is a `php` file..

Then you can use html tags with php scripts, no need to add it using JS.
It's as simple as this:

```
<div>
   <?php echo $PRINTHERE; ?>
</div>
```

Do remember that PHP is server-side and JS is client-side. But if you really want to do that, you can pass a `php` variable like this:

```
<script>
     var print = <?php echo $PRINTHERE; ?>;
     $("#btns").html(Jmol.jmolButton(jmolApplet0, "select atomno="+print+"; halos on;", "frozen on"));
</script>
```